# django variable substitution within include tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I'd like to find a way to conditionally include a file whose filename varies.  In the example below I'd like the template to include para-ford.txt or para-mazda.txt at the relevant times.  This example fails, of course, because the template engine does not substitute {{car.maker}} when inside {% include ... %}.

```
{% for car in cars %}
<p>{% include "para-{{car.maker}}.txt" %}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Each item in the 'cars' collection has a 'maker' property, containing 'ford', 'mazda' etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of solving this would be to add a method on your model:

```
# models.py
class Cars(models.Model):
    maker = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def get_maker_template(self):
        return "para-{0}.txt".format(self.maker)

# template
{% for car in cars %}
<p>{% include car.get_maker_template %}</p>
{% endfor %}
```